# Display the Math Operations in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am a beginner to ASP and I have this code. It suppose to display the sum, product, and average of three numbers from an array in separate text boxes once the button"calculate" is pressed. However, whenever I put three values in text boxes and press calculate it just shows zeros!

```
protected void MathOps(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] arr = new double[3];

    double sum = 0;
    double product = 0;
    double average = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        product *= arr[i];
        average = sum / arr.Length;

        TextBox6.Text = sum.ToString();
        TextBox7.Text = product.ToString();
        TextBox8.Text = average.ToString();
    }
}
```

[This is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8a82.png) of the form for more clarification

Comment: `double[] arr = new double[3];` generates an array of default values - which is `0` for `decimal`

Comment: `double[] arr = new double[3];` means `double[] arr = new double[3] {0, 0, 0};` and so you have `sum = 0 + 0 + 0` etc.

Comment: `double[] arr = new double[] {firstValue, secondValue, thirdValue};`, e.g. `double[] arr = new double[] {double.Parse(textBox1.Text), double.Parse(textBox2.Text), double.Parse(textBox3.Text)};`

Comment: I didn't know that double[] arr = new double[3]; generates zeros

Comment: What did you expect it to do? Fill it with random numbers?

Comment: I have 3 textboxes where i input the numbers that should be calculated

Comment: You know what those boxes represent, .NET does not. You have to write what you want to do as code (well, except where convention is used, but that's not what this kind of thing is).

Comment: Yeah I understand now i didn't link the code with the boxes. very stupid of me. it's my first assignment so yeah i am still figuring it out. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this (simplified code):

```
protected void MathOps(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //TODO: Simplification: we assume all TextBox1.Text..TextBox3.Text have valid values
    double[] arr = new double[] {
      double.Parse(TextBox1.Text), 
      double.Parse(TextBox2.Text),
      double.Parse(TextBox3.Text),  
    };

    double sum = 0;
    double product = 1;
    double average = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += arr[i];
        product *= arr[i];
    }

    average = sum / arr.Length;

    //DONE: There's no need to output in each iteration
    TextBox6.Text = sum.ToString();
    TextBox7.Text = product.ToString();
    TextBox8.Text = average.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it finally worked. I can see my mistakes now they were stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing arr.

```
double [] arr = new double [3]
```

Above line creates an array of 3 doubles and by default the values are 0.0.
So first initialize it

```
protected void MathOps(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double[] arr = new double[3];
    arr[0]  = 3.0, arr[1] =4.0 , arr[2]=5.0


double sum = 0;
double product = 0;
double average = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
{
    sum += arr[i];
    product *= arr[i];
    average = sum / arr.Length;

    TextBox6.Text = sum.ToString();
    TextBox7.Text = product.ToString();
    TextBox8.Text = average.ToString();
}
```

}

This code will work.